# how can i ensure only one user account per UK resident is created on my website?

Tags: user-accounts, user-registration

Does anyone have any ideas as how I could limit a user account on my website to one account per UK citizen?

I have approached the uk Eectoral Roll (http://www.theukelectoralroll.co.uk/) and several other similar companies to ask them how much it would cost to search their database for a positive match when an account is created on my site but I have had no reply from any of them.

Any other ideas would really be appreciated if I can't go down this route.

Answer (score 4):

That's a difficult requirement.  I would ask is it really required that some one can not register twice? What harm will it do to your website?

There is no technological method to do this.  You would have to do some kind of physical identity verification system, eg "send us a copy of the front page of your passport".  Even then you could potentially have one person register several times - I'm sure some people will have more than one passport with different names.

Comment: Yes the physical identification system is a good idea and would work but it would also cause too much admin. I may have to rethink! It would be nice to ensure that only one account per person could be created but it's not fundamental for my idea. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess the combination of name, phone number, e-mail address and normal address should be quite unique?

There is no guarantee you'll have unique users, for example a father and son living at home, sharing his fathers name and using a family e-mail (although the son might be a Jr. in that case, I don't really know about that), but the chance you'll have duplicates is extremely small.

I cannot think of any other way except physical confirmation.

Comment: ... Yes good points - I was dead against the proposed National Identity Cards but in hindsight they'd have been pretty useful for my idea, the unique ID could've been used for registrations :-)